# Using BING Maps SOAP Services in WP7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Can anyone refer me to a tutorial or explain how to consume **BING Maps SearchService (SOAP Webservice)** to find **nearby chemists / pharmacist**. I could not find a single example for consuming the web service on a Windows Phone 7 app.

Also I intend to find the nearby results in **India only**. I think for this, the `culture` needs to be set to `IN`.

Comment: Culture is for the language of the result, not the search area. As someone else said soap has been deprecated and replaced by rest

Answer (score 0):

don't use the SOAP services they are not the preferred service any more, use the REST services instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx